# ReactJS with JQuery - Development and Deployment

Tags: jquery, reactjs, user-interface

UI part in existing web application is based on HTML and JQuery. Is it possible to use ReactJS for new webpages in the same web application? 
Will it be possible to deploy all code together? Generally in ReactJS, final output file will be minified JS and CSS. Can we apply minification for existing JQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

> UI part in existing web application is based on HTML and JQuery. Is it
>   possible to use ReactJS for new webpages in the same web application?

Yes, to start allow jQuery to show/hide the ReactJS page.  As your react portion becomes larger, inverse this with [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/).  Note before taking on React, but sure you know how to write modern javascript without jQuery.   Be sure you have some React experience before adding this complexity.  [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) is a good place to start.

> Will it be possible to deploy all code together?

Yes, a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) can do this, but don't expect to learn it in a day.

> Generally in ReactJS, final output file will be minified JS and CSS.
>   Can we apply minification for existing JQuery code?

Yes, [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) again

Comment: For new functionalities (new webpages within same application), we are planning to use ReactJS. We are not targeting to replace existing JQuery with ReactJS.

Comment: Do you currently have a single page application?

Comment: Yes it's a single page application.